# Hive: Get the list of days for the specified month

Tags: hive

For a given month, say Dec I wanted the following rows as the output.  Is there a way to achieve this with the built-in Hive UDF's?

1-Dec-2016
2-Dec-2016
.
.
.
30-Dec-2016
31-Dec-2016

Found the answer myself (where dual is the dummy table like in ORACLE):

select date_add('2016-11-01',cntr - 1) from 
  (select explode(num) AS cntr from 
    (select array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31) as num from dual) temp1
   ) temp2 
where cntr <= day(last_day('2016-11-01'));

Comment: please update your question in more elaborately. What you are doing, what you want as output and where are you stuck??

Comment: I need a Hive query that can output the above rows

Comment: All I need is the list of dates in a given month, in separate rows.

Comment: Can you please add your table, have you seen https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: see the resolution in my summary

Answer (score 0):

You need a calendar date dimension `date_dim` table in your warehouse. This table should be in every data warehouse for using as a dimension and for situations like yours. I suggest you to create and load this table.  You can generate required rows querying date_dim filtering by year and month.
For example you can download it here: http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/microsoft-data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/ or find some other source or generate your own.
See also this article about date_dim generating: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/647950/create-and-populate-date-dimension-for-data-wareho

Comment: see the resolution in my summary

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_format()` of hive. Assuming your `date_field` variable.

```
select date_format(date_field,'dd-MMM-yyyy') from table1;
```

where `table1` is the table name.